# stream windows media content to iPhone App

Tags: ios, xcode, streaming, libmms

I am currently working on a streaming app which should receive a Windows Media Video stream. I am using libmms to encode the stream.

I took the Wunderradio as reference project. When trying to build the app I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_Status_SetNewStatusString", referenced from:
>         _report_progress in liblibmms.a(mms.o)
>     "_gStopFFMPEG", referenced from:
>         _fallback_io_read in liblibmms.a(mms.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Maybe someone knows what it means and how to fix it?

Thanks for any kind of help and have a nice day.,
MrBr.

Comment: did you even finish this app? I want to do the same..

Comment: Good Luck! I did not finish it. Apple won't approve this kind of pratice "eventually". Thats what they said...

Answer (score 0):

This error occured because of not including the dependencies of the FFMPEG library into the project.

After including it the error is gone and it builds without compiler errors.

Comment: The first error message '_Status_SetNewStatusString (...)' is still there as soon as I call mms_connect(...) - method :-(

Answer (score 0):

"_Status_SetNewStatusString" is not defined in the mms.c, there's a warning about it

You can delete it, it's not used in the new versions anyway.